# Famous messy scientists

Tags: biographical-details, examples, scientists

> **Which scientists were known to be messy?**

I know of [Albert Einstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein):
[image]

And of [Jean Piaget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Piaget):
[image]

Are there other examples?

Comment: The Einstein photo, which is similar (or maybe even identical) to many that I've seen in books, seems pretty tame to me and probably most every research university department (math, physics, history, philosophy, etc.) with more than 10 members has 2 or 3 desks like this (at least, before the 1980s when PC's began taking the place of numerous manuscript writing and refereeing projects). However, the other picture, of someone I don't recognize, is MUCH better. I have seen a few desks like this, but not many, and nearly all such desks that I've seen were before the late 1980s.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro I agree the second is much better :). Very roughly said, Piaget invented pedagogy.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Do you believe I should take away the photo of einstein?

Comment: Incidentally, the second photo looks as if it might be someone going through their stuff prior to cleaning out their office due to retirement. I saw an office like this once during a job interview (Spring 2000 I think), the office being the office I would have gotten had I been offered and accepted the job, as the job search was to replace someone retiring.

Comment: I'd just leave the Einstein photo up for now and see if anyone suggests a replacement after reading our comments.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Piaget was well known to be very messy. I remember (but can't find a reference at the moment) my psychology teacher saying something along the following lines: "Piaget said: There are two types of ordering, the artificial one and the natural one. The artificial one is the one you usually see in any "clean" office and the natural one is chronological. I prefer the second one." It was a long time ago though...

Comment: A better question would be what scientists are known for being amazingly organized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including mathematician [John H Conway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Horton_Conway)
[image: John Horton Conway in his office at Princeton University in 1993.]
John Horton Conway in his office at Princeton University in 1993.

Conway was eventually crowded out of that office, writes biographer Siobhan Roberts, by the "wanton mess that accumulated into a full-fledged tip, with multicoloured paper polyhedra hanging from the ceiling and gigantic spongy Escher puzzle pieces tiling the floor."

Answer (score 2):

Just google "messy professor" images to find lots of them.

[image: Al Gore]